# How can I match the array of strings from a page to the table text in cucumber/capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I write this scenario in cucumber :

```
Then the following drawers should be present on the page
      |Stations  |
      |Categories|
      |Schedules |
      |My Radio  |
```

below are my step definitions :

```
Then(/^the following drawers should be present on the page$/) do |table|

  value = Array.new
  value = "#{table}"
  stats = page.all(:css,'.radionav__panel-item').map(&:text)
 expect(value).to contain_exactly(stats)
end
```

when i print `stats` i got this result : `["Stations", "Categories", "Schedules", "My Radio"]`

and for `value` got :

```
|Stations  |
|Categories|
|Schedules |
|My Radio  |
```

when i try to match both then i got error saying

```
    Then the following drawers should be present on the page # features/step_def
initions/radio_nav_steps.rb:14
      stats : ["Stations", "Categories", "Schedules", "My Radio"]
      | Stations   |
      | Categories |
      | Schedules  |
      | My Radio   |
      expected a collection that can be converted to an array with `#to_ary` or
`#to_a`, but got "\n  | \e[32m    Stations  \e[0m\e[0m |\e[0m\n  | \e[32m    Cat
egories\e[0m\e[0m |\e[0m\n  | \e[32m    Schedules \e[0m\e[0m |\e[0m\n  | \e[32m
   My Radio  \e[0m\e[0m |\e[0m\n" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/radio_nav_steps.rb:22:in `/^the following draw
ers should be present on the page$/'
      features/radio_nav.feature:34:in `Then the following drawers should be pre
sent on the page'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/radio_nav.feature:33 # Scenario: As a user I should see all th
e drawers
```

I just want to match the table element text of cucumber feature file to the text which i got from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me :

```
 Then(/^the following drawers should be present on the page$/) do |table|
  stats = page.all(:css,'.radionav__panel-item').map(&:text)
  data = table.hashes
  begin
    data.each do|row|
      row.each do |key, value|
        if stats.include? value
        else
          puts "element not found"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When passing tables to a cucumber step the table is passed as a cucumber datatable.  This can be converted to an array by calling `raw` on it.

```
Then(/^the following drawers should be present on the page$/) do |table|
  stats = page.all(:css,'.radionav__panel-item').map(&:text)
  expect(table.raw.flatten).to contain_exactly(stats)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert a string to an array.

Try something like this, although I'm not sure what are those escape sequences:

```
value = table.lines.map{ |l| l.match(/\|(.*)\|/)[1].strip }
```